# How would I get the latest tweet from a user and update it it in a UILabel?

Tags: ios, json, twitter, nsstring, uilabel

I'm trying to get the most recent tweet from one twitter account and update that in a UILabel on my view.  The tweet should be stored in a string and updated every time a new tweet is available. I tried using the twitter API with parameters of "screen_name" and "count", and storing all the tweets in an array. When I print the array, it returns a null.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit:
I am getting a "bad authentication data" error now.

```
    NSURL *requestAPI = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json"];

    NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"q": @"@user",
                                                 @"result_type":@"recent",
                                                 @"count": @"1"};

    SLRequest *posts = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter requestMethod:SLRequestMethodGET URL:requestAPI parameters:parameters];

    [posts performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *response, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error){

        self.tweet = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&error];
        NSLog(@"%@",self.tweet);
  }];
```

Comment: No one can help if you don't post your relevant code. Explain what the code is doing and what it is not doing. Provide details about values of your variables when you run the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to obtain the tweets from one specific user, you should probably use App Only Authentication (See link: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/application-only-auth). Also, I would suggest using the [STTwitter](https://github.com/nst/STTwitter) library to simplify things. See code below:

```
STTwitterAPI *twitter = [STTwitterAPI twitterAPIAppOnlyWithConsumerKey:@"CONSUMER KEY" consumerSecret:@"CONSUMER SECRET KEY"];

[twitter verifyCredentialsWithSuccessBlock:^(NSString *username) {

        [twitter getUserTimelineWithScreenName:@"thetwitteraccount" count:100 successBlock:^(NSArray *statuses) {

            self.tweets = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:statuses];

            //Say we want to access the text of the first tweet in the array
            NSDictionary *text = self.tweets[0];
            self.yourlabel.text = text[@"text"];

        } errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {
            code

        }];
    } errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {
        code
    }];
```

Comment: That gives me an array. I would need a string to display it in a uilabel.

Comment: You can create a NSDictionary that will access the index of the array and pass only the text of the tweet. Then you can set the label.text to equal the text of tweet. Pretty simple if you use STTwitter